# PNP powershell SharePoint Online set modern page bannerimageurl

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

My goal is to use PNP commandlets to set the SharePoint online modern bannerimageurl property for a page.

First I get a list of the pages and their current title and bannerimageurl values

```
# Get alist of all pages and their banner URLs
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Fields ID,Title,BannerImageUrl
$items | %{new-object PSObject -Property @{Id=$_["ID"];Title=$_["Title"];BannerImageUrl=$_["BannerImageUrl"].Url}} | select ID,Title,BannerImageUrl
```

But even if I then run the following code to set the BannerImage of one page (say ID2)

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Id 2 -Values @{"BannerImageUrl" = " https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mycomsite3/bannerimages/bread-braid-tedster-sml.jpg";}
```

When I run the following again the item 2 shows up as having a changed BannerImageUrl

```
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Fields ID,Title,BannerImageUrl
$items | %{new-object PSObject -Property @{Id=$_["ID"];Title=$_["Title"];BannerImageUrl=$_["BannerImageUrl"].Url}} | select ID,Title,BannerImageUrl
```

BUT when I actually view the page in the browser that is item 2 there has been no change to the banner image ??

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong when I set the BannerImageUrl.

Your experience and knowledge greatly accepted.

Comment: I've checked using SharePoint designer and when I run code like the following

Set-PnPListItem -List "SitePages" -Id 29 -Values @{"BannerImageUrl" = "";}

The code within the ASPX page is modified to

<mso:BannerImageUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:BannerImageUrl>

But the page when viewed in the borwser doesn't show no bannerimage.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a PS Function for that exact same problem based on the JS Solution [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Changing-a-Page-Banner-Image-inside-a-Modern-Page-using-PnP/td-p/93529), in case you still need it:

```
function UpdateBannerImage {
param(
    [string]$listName,
    [int]$itemId,
    [string]$newBannerUrl
)
#get list item
$item = Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -Id $itemId -Fields LayoutWebpartsContent, BannerImageUrl
if($item["LayoutWebpartsContent"] -match 'data-sp-controldata="([^"]+)"'){
    # get substring w/ regex
    $temp = $item["LayoutWebpartsContent"] | Select-String -Pattern 'data-sp-controldata="([^"]+)"'
    $content = $temp.Matches.Groups[1].Value
    # replace [] bc sometimes it throws later
    $content = $content.replace("[","&#91;").replace("]","&#93;")
    # decode 
    $dec = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($content)
    # from JSON
    $jnContent = ConvertFrom-Json $dec

    #set values
    if (!$jnContent.serverProcessedContent) {
        $jnContent.serverProcessedContent = {};
    }
    if (!$jnContent.serverProcessedContent.imageSources) {
        $jnContent.serverProcessedContent.imageSources = New-Object PSObject;
        $jnContent.serverProcessedContent.imageSources | add-member Noteproperty imageSource $newBannerUrl
    }
    if(!$jnContent.serverProcessedContent.imageSources.imageSource){
        $jnContent.serverProcessedContent.imageSources | add-member Noteproperty imageSource $newBannerUrl
    }
    $jnContent.serverProcessedContent.imageSources.imageSource = $newBannerUrl

    # need to always create new properties, otherwise nothing changes
    $curTitle = "";
    if($jnContent.properties){
        $curTitle = $jnContent.properties.title;
    }
        $jnContent.properties = New-Object PSObject;
    $jnContent.properties | add-member Noteproperty title $curTitle
    $jnContent.properties | add-member Noteproperty imageSourceType 2

    # to JSON
    $newContent = $jnContent | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    $enc = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($newContent)
    $enc = $enc.replace("{","&#123;").replace(":","&#58;").replace("}","&#125;").replace("[","&#91;").replace("]","&#93;")

    # replace full item property
    $fullContent = $item["LayoutWebpartsContent"].replace("[","&#91;").replace("]","&#93;");
    $fullContent = $fullContent -replace $content, $enc
    $fullContent.replace("&#91;","[").replace("&#93;","]")

    # set & update
    $item["LayoutWebpartsContent"] = $fullContent
    $item.Update()

    # not really sure if needed, but also update bannerURL
    Set-PnPListItem -List $listName -Id $itemId -Values @{"BannerImageUrl" = $newBannerUrl; }
    }
}
```

new here sorry if i mess up the format, also uploaded for safety [here](https://github.com/Sohryu7/SPO-Scripts) :P

Comment: Awesome stuff! Thanks!
Now all I need to figure out is how to move the image like I can do in the UI! :)

Comment: if you look at the content of $item["LayoutWebpartsContent"] after moving the image it has 2 new properties: "properties":"title":"StartPage","imageSourceType":2,**"translateX":46.489859594383773,"translateY":21.052631578947366**}}", you can copy those too in the code or calculate them

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out!

Comment: Not sure why, but the first time I ran this function and supplied all the correct details for the parameters - it worked fine.

Now I can't get it to work at all.

PNP Powershell is a bit of a pain sometimes!

Did the March 2018 update break this script?